# Retroactive calculation of VM instance total running time (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a number of instances in a GCP project, that I want to check retroactively how long they've been in use in the last 30 days, i.e. sum the total time an instance is **not** stopped or terminated during a specific month.

Does anyone know if this can be calculated, and if so - how?
Or maybe another idea that would allow me to sum the total time an instance was in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079794/how-to-get-uptime-total-and-percentage-of-gcp-compute-vm-instance-through-mql) other post, I would recommend something like:

```
fetch gce_instance
| metric 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime'
| align delta(30d)
| every 30d
| group_by [metric.instance_name]
```

I would also consider creating uptime_checks as one of the answers in said post recommends for future checks, but those wouldn't work retroactively. If you need more info about MQL you can find it [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/quickstart).